# XML-RPC object mapping

Tags: proxy, service, xml-rpc, data-mapping

Recently I was working on web services proxy. I got 2 web services proxy. UI will call **Proxy A** to let say create a record. then what **Proxy A** will do is to call **Proxy B** to do the actual task which create the record (For some reason must go through **Proxy A**) now the problem is When UI call **Proxy A**, **Proxy A** will pass the objectA to **Proxy B** createRecord method which take in another different object type. Anyone came across this problem before can give me some suggestion. Instead of convert object A to object B.

Comment: How can I map the objectA to objectB

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought to use xsl in order to transform you ProxyA request into ProxyB request?
http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/

Comment: Hi I just start using web services not really sure, can you roughly explain to me how XSL work in order to map the objects together?

Comment: Hi,

Fist of all, little clarification -XSL is a conversion tool for XML, it's not related directly to web services.

Few words regards XSL - usually you will use XSL in order to convert XML to an HTML document, but you may use it for XML format conversions (XML A ---> XML B).
XSL itself consist of a scripting language encoded in XML format :-). In the link I've attached you may see example of using it.

Hope that I helped you.
Shay